# WMI - Query from multiple classes in VC++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, notifications, wmi

i am using MSstudio 2010 and vc++ platform. I want to query and receive notification from multiple classes of WMI from a remote machine. I am able receive notification from 1 class ,ex. notification of changes in network adapter .
Is there any way i can query from multiple classes separately (not filtering) in c++ ??

Using " ManagementObjectSearcher " is 1 option on c# ,but i want it on c++ specifically!!
Has anyone done similar thing or is there some alternative ?
Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Not sure about your question, but you can create classes that derive from IWbemObjectSink and use the ExecNotificationQueryAsync of the IWbemServices to receive the notifications.

Comment: Thanks for the reply . I have done the same thing for receiving notification using 1 class. My question is how to use more than 1 class independently(no AND or OR). Is there any thread services or something ? or if i can use SYSTEM namespace on vc++ ?

Comment: Just want a direction. Dont want to waste 2-3 days pondering and get no result !!!

Comment: Why don't you create X sinks each one for a diferent notification (ex. MSNdis_NotifyAdapterRemoval and MSNdis_StatusMediaDisconnect) and register both, I think I'm not seeing the problem.

Comment: You cannot receive notifications from multiples WMI classes. You must create a SINK for each class which you want inspect.